# How does dieharder know when processing binary numbers from a file how "long" these numbers are?

Tags: random

I want to examine the random numbers generated by a random number generator. Each random number is 4 bytes. I have collected 50,000 numbers, each number is in a separate file (so I have 50,000 files each containing 4 bytes).
I'd like [dieharder](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dieharder) (a testing and benchmarking tool for random number generators) to benchmark these random numbers.

dieharder supports multiple ways of feeding random bytes. For feeding ASCII numbers it supports a header format where one can define "numbit". According to the man page this looks like that:

```
dieharder -g 202 -f testrands.txt -a
```

Where testrands.txt should consist of a header such as:

```
#==================================================================
# generator mt19937_1999 seed = 1274511046
#==================================================================
type: d
count: 100000
numbit: 32
3129711816
85411969
2545911541
```

Now it also supports raw binary data:

```
dieharder -g 201 -f testrands.bin -a
```

My question is:
How would dieharder then know that my original numbers were 4 bytes long (it would only see a stream of 50,000 * 4 bytes)?

Comment: Please give appropriate links to `dieharder` (not everyone knows what you are talking about) as well as a [mcve] which illustrates the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest solution be to convert your data to ASCII?

Comment: I edited the question. Is it clear now? @500-InternalServerError: I know, but that is not the question, I'd like to understand the raw binary processing.

Comment: For binary data, length is irrelevant. Random bytes, random words, random longs, should all be indistinguishable from random bits.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker That's what I wonder. Is it really like that? Does that mean I can always "concatenate" random data of arbitrary length and test it for randomness? I wondered about that also with tools like this one: https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/random-bit-generation/documentation-and-software

Comment: It's true if the numbers are uniformly distributed over a range of values that is a power of two. Obviously you couldn't do that with a set of random 8-digit decimal numbers, for example.

Comment: But that's what I want to find out. I actually don't know if they are uniformly distributed.

Comment: If they're not, dieharder will tell you, quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

> Raw binary input reads 32 bit increments of the specified data stream.

So, the binary file has to contain (random) numbers which are each 4 bytes long

Comment: it also means, we don't need to make a header for this binary file and the numbers should be presented line by line?

Comment: no header and no new lines needed, from the manual: "Raw binary input reads 32 bit increments of the specified data stream" on https://manpages.debian.org/testing/dieharder/dieharder.1.en.html